# Optional ofNullable on nested reference to object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I need to check if my reference to object return null, So I use Optional like below:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(model.getSomeField().getUserName()).orElse("No name");
```

and right now, Optional return me NullPointerException because I have a null on `model.getSomeField()`, how to check for all of the null's in the reference that is passed in the `Optional.ofNullable`? For example, if `model.getSomeField()` is null or `model.getSomeField().getUserName()` is null then i want to run `orElse` clause.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function))

`return Optional.ofNullable(model).map(Model::getSomeField).map(Field::getUserName).orElse("No name");`